# Reading from TCP socket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp, endianness

I have to receive data from TCP socket. It has fixed 16-bytes header (one header's field is data length) and data. I receive it with BigEndian, but it was send with LittleEndian.

I can' find good solution for such a data reception. What is working for me now is (reading one of the header fields):

```
QByteArray packetType = tcpSocket->read(2);
QDataStream in(packetType);
in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
quint16 pT = 0;
in >> pT;
```

Is there any better way to set QByteArray endianess?
Or a way to read specified number of bytes with QDataStream?

Comment: What don't you like about the code you have written?

Comment: Fix the source! It should not have been sent as little endian in the first place.

Comment: @DaleWilson I believe there is "less lines" solution.

Comment: @Arunmu I can't. The source is Delphi 7 software which I can't edit.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost doing it right. The intermediate `QByteArray` is unnecessary. You can set the data stream directly on the socket:

```
QTcpSocket socket;
QDataStream in(&socket);
in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
...
void onReadyRead() {
  in.startTransaction();
  uint16_t packet_type;
  in >> packet_type;
  if (in.status == QDataStream::Ok) {
    if (packet_type == Foo) {
      uint32_t foo_data;
      in >> foo_data;
      if (! in.commitTransaction())
        return; // not enough data
      // got a full packet here
    }
  }
  in.abortTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Could you please help more with it? The full header is like:
`uint64_t headerID;
uint16_t packetType;
uint16_t length;
uint16_t arg1;
uint16_t arg2;`

I tried to read it with:
`in >> headerID >> packetType >> length >> arg1 >> arg2;`
but it is not possible due to >> operator on uint64_t variable.

Comment: You need to implement that operator yourself, then :) Just look at how Qt implemented them and do more of the same.

Comment: ok, I found Qt has it defined for `quint64` :) But after header I have data with length of 2140 bytes in that case. Part of it are integers, part are strings. I read it now with: `char *temp = new char[length]; in.readRawData(temp,length)`, but no idea yet how to split it to separate variables in a sense how to convert char table to integers and strings.

Comment: @bLAZ Probably you don't have to read it as raw data. Read it as individual items. You'll have to update your question with details of exactly what you're doing. The back-and-forth indicates a deficiency in your question.